# ST3: Find text results in panel instead of a buffer

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I must have hit a setting in ST3 and caused my program to display results in a panel instead of in a buffer. How do I get it back so that find-text results go into their own tab? I've done some digging around but I can't find what I did.

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Find in Files` panel, there is a series of buttons to the left of the `Find` field, and the right most one of those is the one that controls whether the find results show up in a panel or in a buffer.

Note that the button may look different in your version as it appears that you're using a different theme (the image below shows the default theme). You can verify that you have the correct button based on the tool tip text.

[image: Find in Files panel]

Comment: Ugh, that's it. Crisis averted! Thanks OdatNurd.